# AWS IAM Policies: Why Don't Some Services Support Wildcards For Certain Fields In Arns?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

The [AWS CodeStar docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dtconsole/latest/userguide/security-iam.html#security_iam_access-manage) say:

> You can use wildcards only with the connection resources listed in the following table. You can't use wildcards with region or account-id resources.

But other services do allow you to use wildcards for region and account-id.  What determines when wildcards can be used for these fields in an Arn?  Any insight into how this works would be helpful.  I don't see it in the doc on [IAM identifiers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_identifiers.html).

Comment: This is probably not a question according the SO policy and I do not have any correct answer, but it seems to me (based on reviewing IAM policies for a few years now) that it really depends on the implementation details of a given service. The IAM policies are not static too. They are updated all the time. One day an action supports only a star, the next day you can use arn wildcards. Resource policies support different things than identity policies. Some api calls suddenly require additional iam action... Always use the docs. If the docs is wrong, contact support. They will fix it eventually